# how to get rails app working locally after heroku clone?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

My local code got messed up so I would like to download the version off heroku and start using that. I ran this to download

```
heroku git:clone -a myapp
```

then I installed taps using

```
gem install taps
```

then I ran

```
heroku db:pull
```

Is this all that's required? Just want to make sure that I don't mess up anything and can easily redeploy using git push heroku master later.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to pull code directly from Heroku, but I'm not sure why you would need to, since "git push heroku master" just pushes the master branch of your code from your Git repository to Heroku.  Unless you've pushed your "dirty" code to Git, you should just be able to remove the bad code locally and do a "git pull" to get the good code from your Git repository directly.